# SSA generation using Cytron's algorithm

Tags: compiler-construction, graph-theory, ssa

I'm trying to generate SSA using Cytron's [algorithm](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/%7Epingali/CS380C/2010/papers/ssaCytron.pdf)
Everything seems to work fine but for some test case I'm getting a problem. I have the following loop test example setup:
[image]

My problem arises with definition of `w8` on node `0x100003f50`.
The nodes that has `0x100003f50` as a node in their dominance frontier set and have `w8` as definition are:
`0x100003f64`
`0x100003f50`
`0x100003fa8`

*NOTE* that node `0x100003fa8` has not definitions initially, on the second iteration it does have `w8` definition of the form of phi assignment from nodes `0x100003f90` and `0x100003f78`.

So after the phi function insertion step we have 3 arguments to phi assignment for definition `w8` in node `0x100003f50`.

Next to the rename step, where we replace the phi variables with their corresponding definition from the predecessor of the block that defines a phi assignment, in this case `0x100003f50`, the `0x100003f50` node has only 2 predecessor, making the substitution of the phi arguments of `w8` missing a rename, and not only that it doesn't make a-lot of sense to me to just iterate the successors of blocks to replace their phi function arguments with the corresponding block index, since in the classic example:

[image]

It seems to work fine that each of the predecessor of the block defining the phi function also has the block as its dominance frontier, in my example the predecessor of the test block defining the phi function for `w8`, that is block `0x100003f50`, has the entry block and the loop edge node as predecessor, leaving out one of the phi arguments unchanged, so I wonder what am I missing here?

Comment: Excuse my ARM ignorance but it seems to me that block `0x100003f50` does not have `w8` as an input. It has the variable at `[sp]` as an input though.

Comment: @harold You're correct but it doesn't matter as it will later be eliminated in dead code elimination phase, but the algorithm to transform to ssa should just place the phi nodes for all *possible* inputs even if not used yet. In my example it seems to insert another variables as a possible source of input into the phi assignment of `w8` which I can only figure I need to coalesce with my proposed answer, which again is not a definite answer, maybe someone with more experience on the topic could clarify about this example.

Comment: It is my understanding that, while Cytron's classic algorithm does that, it's not required and various alternative SSA-construction algorithms create (semi)pruned SSA to begin with.

Comment: @harold yea but my question relate to the inserting oh phi nodes, before even talking about pruning, my example shows that there's extra variable in the phi assignment unless some coalescing is done or I'm just wrong about my understanding of the algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's the correct answer or I just missed something but I came up with the idea that if the current node has somewhere in the dominator tree a node which isn't the frontier node in question, which also has the same frontier node, then I don't insert another phi argument for this special case.

Here's a partial fix written in python:

```py
                        # Cases where node has a doiminator which also defines the symbol
                        # and both has the same frontier node (can happen in loop)
                        # and so the dominator dominates the definition of the symbol of the
                        # current node then we don't need to insert another variable to the
                        # phi assingment of the frontiner node
                        idom = node.idom
                        quit = False
                        while idom != None and idom != frontier_node:
                            if frontier_node in idom.dominance_frontier and idom in procedure.symbol_defs[sym]:
                                quit = True
                                break
                            idom = idom.idom
                        
                        if quit: # continue to the next node in the enacpsuling loop of phi nodes insertion
                            continue
```

**EDIT**:
I actually found this presentation [https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~pekhimenko/courses/cscd70-w20/docs/Lecture%204%20[SSA]%2002.03.2020.pdf](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Epekhimenko/courses/cscd70-w20/docs/Lecture%204%20%5BSSA%5D%2002.03.2020.pdf)

Which illustrate Cytron's algorithm on page 26 and states a condition for insertion of phi node (before describing the algorithm in terms of dominance frontiers):

- There exists a non-empty path from x to z, Pxz
- and a non-empty path from y to z, Pyz

S.t Pxz Union Pyz = { z }
(Z is only common block along paths)

Which makes sense to what I've did with the coalescing